# Gradient on text causing keyframe animation to render incorrectly

Tags: css, gradient, keyframe

I am trying to animate some text which has a gradient on it. I'm using a simple css keyframe to bring it in and change the opacity.

How ever, the text with the gradient isn't fully rendering in after the animation is completed. Sometimes the opacity doesn't fully work.

I've included a h1 and h2 tag. The h1 tag is the text with the issue, h2 is to demonstrate how it should look without the gradient causing issues

Here is a pen link: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jRMKBQ

Code is also below

```css
@keyframes text {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(100px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0.2;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.text {
  transform: translateY(100px);
  opacity: 0;
  animation: text 1s ease forwards;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 4rem;
  color: black;
  padding: 20px 0px;
  font-weight: bold;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  text-fill-color: transparent;
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #e64c4c 0%, #ef32fb 100%);
}

h2 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 4rem;
  color: black;
  padding: 20px 0px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="text">Explore some of our recent work</h1>

<h2 class="text">Explore some of our recent work</h2>
```

Comment: checked on chrome in mac machine..working fine

Comment: Just tried chrome myself and it worked. Is this a firefox issue?

Comment: try to add `-moz-` prefix in your animation

Comment: This didn't seem to work. It appears I have to add the animation to the parent class which holds the text. Firefox doesn't seem to animate and clip at the same time